Given $A=\{1,2,...,11\}$. How many function $f:A\to A$ satisfy $x=f^{f(x)}(x)=(f\circ f\circ ...\circ f)(x)$ ($f$ symbol appear $f(x)$ times)
Given $A=\{1,2,3,...,11\}$. How many function $f:A\to A$ satisfy $$x=f^{f(x)}(x)=(f\circ f\circ ...\circ f)(x)$$ ($f$ symbol appear $f(x)$ times)
for every $x\in A$
So constant functions don't work, I misunderstand about the problem itself. Now the only map I can imagine is identity map. I try to find any simple permutation map, probably will be depend to whether the image odd or even number, but I still cannot figure.

I suggest:  start by doing this for a smaller number than $11$.

Nice idea, I will try it

Try finding convenient permutations maybe? Reason with the orders of the cycle

Also:  I don't understand why you think constants work.  No matter how many times you iterate a constant, it's still just the same constant.  The identity map works, if you want a simple example.

Oh silly me. You are right. Constant functions don't work.

First, note that $f$ must be surjective because every $x$ is in the image of $f$. Since the domain and codomain have the same size, $f$ must be a bijection, or equivalently, a permutation of $A$. Consider a cycle in this permutation:
$$
x\to y\to z \to \cdots \to w\to x,
$$
i.e., $f(x) = y$, $f(y) = z$, … , $f(w) = x$. Then, to satisfy $x=f^{f(x)}(x)= f^y(x)$, we need $y$ to be a multiple of the length of the cycle. Repeating this for other elements of the cycle, we need all elements in the cycle to be multiples of the length of the cycle. In particular, this means:

$f(1)=1$.
The length of any cycle is at most $3$ because there are fewer than $n$ multiples of $n$ in $A$ for $n>3$.
So, $f(5)=5$, $f(7)=7$, and $f(11)=11$.
$3$ can be in a $1$-cycle or a $3$-cycle.

In the first case, we have $f(3)=3$ and $f(9)=9$. The remaining elements are $\{2,4,6,8,10\}$, and we can form either five $1$-cycles, or one $2$-cycle and three $1$-cycles, or two $2$-cycles and one $1$-cycle with them. In total, there are $$1+\binom52+\frac12\binom52\binom32= 26$$solutions in this case.
In the second case, the $3$-cycle is either $3\to6\to9\to3$ or $3\to9\to6\to3$. The remaining elements are $\{2,4,8,10\}$, and we can form either four $1$-cycles, or one $2$-cycle and two $1$-cycles, or two $2$-cycles with them. In total, there are $$2\times\left[1+\binom42+\frac12\binom42\right]=20$$ solutions in this case.



Therefore, there are $26+20=46$ functions $f$ that satisfy the given requirement.

Thanks for the solution. Honestly, this is very hard for me to digest. However, I will try and will let you know if there is any part I don't understand.
